# How to transfer an activity to a fragment to add a navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm still new to android dev and I wanted to add a navigation drawer to begin to expand the app I'm developing. It appears navigation drawers only work with Fragments. However, my main activity is already pretty deeply involved and I'm not sure how to turn it into a fragment.

```
public class ToolReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ToolListFragment.OnToolSelectedListener, CompatActionBarNavListener, OnClickListener {

boolean mIsDualPane = false;

ToolListFragment mToolListFragment;
InfoFragment mInfoFragment;
Fragment mContent;

int mCatIndex = 0;
int mToolIndex = 0;
ToolsCategory mCurrentCat;

final String[] CATEGORIES = { "top_stories", "us", "politics", "economy" }; //TODO Define categories here

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    // find our fragments
    mToolListFragment = (ToolListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.toolList);
    mInfoFragment = (InfoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.toolInfo);

    mToolListFragment.setContext(this);

    View infoView = findViewById(R.id.toolInfo);
    mIsDualPane = infoView != null && infoView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    mToolListFragment.setOnToolSelectedListener(this);

    int catIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 : savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0);
    setUpActionBar(mIsDualPane, catIndex);

    mToolListFragment.setSelectable(mIsDualPane);
    restoreSelection(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's instance
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

void restoreSelection(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        setNewsCategory(savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0));
        if (mIsDualPane) {
            int toolIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("toolIndex", 0);
            mToolListFragment.setSelection(toolIndex);
            onToolSelected(toolIndex);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    restoreSelection(savedInstanceState);
}

public void setUpActionBar(boolean showTabs, int selTab) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        // No action bar for you!
        // But do not despair. In this case the layout includes a bar across the
        // top that looks and feels like an action bar, but is made up of regular views.
        return;
    }
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    // Set up a CompatActionBarNavHandler to deliver us the Action Bar nagivation events
    CompatActionBarNavHandler handler = new CompatActionBarNavHandler(this);
    if (showTabs) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < CATEGORIES.length; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(CATEGORIES[i]).setTabListener(handler));
        }
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(selTab);
    }
    else {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        SpinnerAdapter adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.actionbar_list_item,
                CATEGORIES);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adap, handler);
    }
    // Show logo instead of icon+title.
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setNewsCategory(0);
}

void setNewsCategory(int categoryIndex) {
    mCatIndex = categoryIndex;
    mCurrentCat = ToolsSource.getInstance(this).getCategory(categoryIndex);
    mToolListFragment.loadCategory(categoryIndex, this);
    // If we are displaying the article on the right, we have to update that too
    if (mIsDualPane) {
        mInfoFragment.displayTool(mCurrentCat.getTool(0));
    }
    // If we are displaying a "category" button (on the ActionBar-less UI), we have to update
    // its text to reflect the current category.

    //Button catButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categorybutton);
    //if (catButton != null) {
    //    catButton.setText(CATEGORIES[mCatIndex]);
    //}
}

@Override
public void onToolSelected(int index) {
    mToolIndex = index;
    if (mIsDualPane) {
        // display it on the article fragment
        mInfoFragment.displayTool(mCurrentCat.getTool(index));
    }
    else {
        // use separate activity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("catIndex", mCatIndex);
        i.putExtra("toolIndex", index);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCategorySelected(int catIndex) {
    setNewsCategory(catIndex);
}

/** Save instance state. Saves current category/article index. */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("catIndex", mCatIndex);
    outState.putInt("toolIndex", mToolIndex);
    //Save the fragment's instance
    if(mInfoFragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mInfoFragment);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/** Called when news category button is clicked.
 *
 * This is the button that we display on UIs that don't have an action bar. This button
 * calls up a list of news categories and switches to the given category.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select a Category");
    builder.setItems(CATEGORIES, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            setNewsCategory(which);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog d = builder.create();
    d.show();
}
}
```

It was something that already was a layout that inserted a fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:id="@+id/toolList"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:name="com.anothergamedesigner.ContactFormTest.ToolListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/tool_listing" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So now I guess I have to turn an activity that inserts a fragment into a fragment that inserts a nested fragment and still retains all the same functions (including passing the context from the new activity as there are some classes in the fragments that requires the context later).

Here's what I've tried to do so far:

```
1) Removed the setTheme, super.onCreate, and setContentView
2) Put getActivity() in front of all getSupportFragmentManagers
3) Put getActivity() in front of getMenuInflater()
4) Put ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()) in front of getSupportActionBar()
5) Changed all this.context to getActivity().
```

This fixed most of my issues, now I'm receiving only two errors. Two "Method does not override superclass" errors for onCreateOptionsMenu and onRestoreInstanceState.

I'm not sure if there are things I should be moving into my new main activity. Also I'm not inflating any view in my new fragment yet, and I'm exactly sure how I would go about making sure everything does its job the same. I think I should change onCreate to onCreateView, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about it.

Here is the new main activity for reference:

```
public class NavDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];

    drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.icon, "Create");
    drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.icon, "Read");
    drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.icon, "Help");

    DrawerItemAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.navdrawer_list_item, drawerItem);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new InfoFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new InfoFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new InfoFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
}
```

In summary:

What I want is to add a navigation drawer, thus turn my main activity into a fragment

What I've tried already is listed above.

What I need to know are how to resolve the two errors I ran into, whether there are any other changes I should be aware of due to being a novice (or should make just because they are smarter or better design), and how to best handle inflating this view.